# C# Regex optional url parameter

Tags: c#, regex

I need to build a REGEX with that will validate an optional numeric only URL parameter

Matches:`/user/123
/user/
/user`

No Matches:`/user/test
/user/123.3`

Best I came up with is

`^\user\b(\/)?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$`

but it fails first no match test.

Comment: Try `^/user(?:/\d+)?/?$`, see [his demo](https://regex101.com/r/1E9LUl/1).

Comment: Your regex is fine and you just forgot to put a `/` before `user` in your regex. Try this `^\/user\b(\/)?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CSgj8h/1)

Comment: Thanks, but this still matches "user/test"

Comment: @Dmitriy: No it doesn't match `user/test` [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/CSgj8h/2)

Comment: Oops, I meant **t**his demo :) So, does https://regex101.com/r/1E9LUl/1 work for you? Is `/user/123/` also possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your regex, the backslash should become a forward slash. You could omit the word boundary `\b` if you use 1 optional group that matches either `/` followed by 1+ digits or a single `/`.

The `(?:0|[1-9]\d*` will match either a single zero or or from 1 up. If you want to match 1+ digits you could use `\d+`

For example using an alternation:

```
^/user(?:/\d+|/)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TMjV66/1/)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `/user`
- `(?:/\d+|/)?` Optional non capturing group to match either / and 1+ digits or /
- `$` End of the string

Or the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/TMjV66/2) including the pattern for the digits:

```
^/user(?:/(?:0|[1-9]\d*)|/)?$
```